# Coding Background images

Tags: image, background

I'm such a newbie to the whole html/css thing, so please bear with my naivety!

I am looking at CSS Zen garden and trying to locate the images used in the designs, using web inspector. The current page I'm looking at is: http://www.csszengarden.com/218//.

I have found the bottle and the "guy pointing" but oddly enough, they are not in the html, but rather in the css....I'm confused, as I thought all content had to be in the html?

Also: for the life of me, I was unable to locate the image of the man looking sideways with the red cross overtop.  Where is the link for this?

Thanks,
B.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the .benefits p:after class, as another background image:
 background:  url('img-look-right-sm.png') no-repeat center 7.75rem;

You can test that by going to that image only:
http://www.csszengarden.com/218/img-look-right-sm.png

I bet if you buy their book, it would explain all that :)

Comment: Thanks Nerf! Okay....so still stumped about it not being in the html...will have to look into learning more about this. :)

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule about where it shows up.  I don't think CSS has a provision for URL of foreground images, but obviously background images can and often should be in the style sheets.  Although in the page you refer to, it looks like a foreground image since there's nothing in front of it.

Comment: If that stumps you, just wait until you run into ASP and PHP.  The code you see is not quite the code being loaded and trying to track things down becomes yet again more difficult.

Comment: thanks....then, why can't I see it easily in the code? When I directly select it using "Inspect this element" I can't actually locate it in the elements section of the web inspector. I have to go to resources tab and then check the style sheet. Seems counter-intuitive to me.